# Как получить правильный размер ячейки RecyclerView StaggeredGridLayout?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Ситуация такая, мне нужно с web показать картинку в RecyclerView

Для загрузки я использую `Glide`

Проблема вот в чем некоторые изображения грузятся нормально и выглядят вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А некоторые грузятся криво и выглядят вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю проблема в том, что RecyclerView создает ячейку быстрее, чем Glide асинхронно получает картинку. RecyclerView не знает какого размера создать ячейку и делает ее максимально большой, после чего картинка становится доступна и устанавливается в ячейку, но ячейка к тому моменту имеет размер намного больший чем необходимо...

Вот XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingEnd="8dp"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/cardMainActivityLinearLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMainCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/standard_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewMainCard"
        >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvBrandName"
          android:text="custom brand"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
          android:text="custom Type"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:layout_below="@+id/tvBrandName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
          android:text="custom price"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/bAction"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="button"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

          />

    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

И вот так в адаптере в `onBindViewHolder()` я использую `Glide`

```
ImageView iv = currentView.ivMainCard;
        String url = currentCard.getImageUrl();

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .crossFade()
                .into(iv);
```

что делаю не так?

Если забыл что то добавить, спрашивайте

Comment: Это то, что вам надо? https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/601

Comment: @Flippy что то я не понял что там мне надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение

В моем случае я просто поменял либу с `Glide` на `Picasso` и сейчас все работает

вот так выглядит мой запрос

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .error(R.drawable.image_error_404)
                .into(iv);
```

Comment: плюс к `Picasso` :)